# Solve an equation with specific domain?

Tags: equation-solving, variable

How can I write a code in Mathematica to solve an equation with variable in specific domains? For instance, I want to write a code for

```
Solve[{2 x + 1 == y && x > 0 && y > 0}, {x, y}, Integers] // Column
```

with extra conditions that $x\in\{1,5,8,17,31,111\}$. How can I put this condition inside the command *Solve[ ]* among other conditions?

Comment: When the list is a finite set, could just make an equation: `In[51]:= xlist = {1, 5, 8, 17, 31, 111};
Solve[{2 x + 1 == y && x > 0 && y > 0 && 
   Apply[Times, x - xlist] == 0}, {x, y}, Integers]

Out[52]= {{x -> 1, y -> 3}, {x -> 5, y -> 11}, {x -> 8, 
  y -> 17}, {x -> 17, y -> 35}, {x -> 31, y -> 63}, {x -> 111, 
  y -> 223}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to insert all the equalities directly:

```
set = {1, 5, 8, 17, 31, 111};
Solve[{2 x + 1 == y && x > 0 && y > 0 && 
    Or @@ (Equal[x, #] & /@ set)}, {x, y}, Integers] // Column
```

Comment: thanks, Do you think it is possible to use something such as "Element" or "Member" here instead of " Or @@ (Equal[x, #] & /@ set)"?

Comment: I don't know, It doesn't seem to work in `Solve` as well as in `Reduce`. Here is another variant of the same direct approach: `Solve[{2 x + 1 == y && x > 0 && y > 0 && 
   Times@@(x-set)==0, {x, y}, Integers] // Column`

Comment: thanks for your quick and new answer!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

```
xlist = {1, 5, 8, 17, 31, 111};

Table[{x, y} /. Solve[2 x + 1 == y && y > 0, y, Integers][[1]],{x, xlist}]

(* {{1, 3}, {5, 11}, {8, 17}, {17, 35}, {31, 63}, {111, 223}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Or more simply,

```
{#, 2 # + 1} & /@ xlist

(* {{1, 3}, {5, 11}, {8, 17}, {17, 35}, {31, 63}, {111, 223}} *)
```