# Solving a system of inequalities where some of the variables are integer-valued, and some are real-valued

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I'd like to know how to ask the *Reduce* command to solve over one domain for certain variables, and another domain for other variables. For example, I'd like to solve the system of inequalities

$$ 2 a + b^2 + c + d \geq 0 , \quad 7 c - 4 d \leq 0 $$

for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$. I've tried

`Reduce[{2 a + b^2 + c + d >= 0, 7 c - 4 d <= 0 && Or @@ (Equal[a, #] & /@ Integers) && Or @@ (Equal[b, #] & /@ Integers) && Or @@ (Equal[c, #] & /@ Reals) && Or @@ (Equal[d, #] & /@ Reals)}, {a, b, c, d}, Reals]`

along the lines of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171636) question, but I think because $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are not finite, and because I'm using *Reduce* rather than *Solve*, something is going wrong (I get an error messsage saying that the above is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `Reduce[{2 a + b^2 + c + d >= 0 , 7 c - 4 d <= 0, 
  a ∈ Integers , b ∈ Integers , c ∈ Reals ,
   d ∈ Reals}, {a, b, c, d}]
`

Comment: Ah, great - thanks! I didn't realise you could simply use the $\in$ symbol in Mathematica.

Comment: Get a graphical overview with  `red[a_, b_] = 
 Reduce[{2 a + b^2 + c + d >= 0, 
   7 c - 4 d <= 0, {a, b} \[Element] Integers, {c, d} \[Element] 
    Reals}, {a, b, c, d}]; Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[red[Sequence @@ ab], {c, -10, 10}, {d, -10, 10}, 
  ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> {"a", "b"} -> ab, 
  FrameLabel -> {"c", "d"}, 
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], 
    Range[-10, 10, 1]}], {ab, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, {1, 1}}] `

Comment: @Akku14 Thanks for this!